Visual Studio compile error C2148 if std::new ...[length] if length > 0xffffffff
I'm doing a build on Visual Studio in 64 bit mode, and get error
c2148 - total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes,
but the actual threshold is 0xffffffff for std::new and doesn't
appear to have a limit if using malloc instead.
I have largeaddressaware option set.
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
#define NEW 0
#if 1
// error c2148 - total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes
#define LEN (4ull*1024ull*1024ull*1024ul)        // 0x100000000
#else
// no compile error even with NEW
#define LEN (4ull*1024ull*1024ull*1024ull-1ull)  // 0x0ffffffff
#endif
int main(void)
{
uint8_t *arr;
size_t i;
int usednew;
    usednew = 1;
    arr = NULL;
#if NEW
    arr = new(std::nothrow) uint8_t [LEN];
#else
    if(arr == NULL){
        usednew = 0;
        arr = (uint8_t *)malloc(LEN);
    }
#endif
    for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        arr[i] = (uint8_t)i;

    for(i = 1; i < LEN; i++){
        if(arr[i-1] > arr[i]){
            std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(usednew)
        delete[] arr;
    else
        free(arr);
    return(0);
}


You've discovered a sign extension bug.  But what exactly is your question?

@DrewDormann - this is not a sign extension bug, since 0xffffffff is working. The error occurs at 0x100000000, not at 0x80000000.

This problem was fixed in an update for Visual Studio 2022. You either did not get the update or you are using an older version of Visual Studio.

I'm on Windows 7, so stuck with Visual Studio 2015. I'll just use malloc on large arrays for now.
